# Parsing a text file using pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following csv file:

```
Filesystem,Size,Used,Avail,Use,Mounted,on
/dev/sda3,196G,124G,63G,67,/
tmpfs,32G,144K,32G,1,/dev/shm
/dev/sda1,194M,42M,143M,23,/boot
```

I'm reading the file using the following code:

```
df = pandas.read_csv(tempFolder+"diskSpace.txt", sep=',',header=None)
```

I tried to print the Use column with three different approaches:

```
 print(df[Use])

 print(df['Use']) 

 print(df["Use"])
```

It fails to print the Use column

Comment: ... what error?

Comment: It looks like you have a header.

Answer (score 4):

Remove `header=None`:

```
In [9]: df = pd.read_csv('data', sep=',')

In [10]: df
Out[10]: 
  Filesystem  Size  Used Avail  Use   Mounted  on
0  /dev/sda3  196G  124G   63G   67         / NaN
1      tmpfs   32G  144K   32G    1  /dev/shm NaN
2  /dev/sda1  194M   42M  143M   23     /boot NaN

In [11]: df['Use']
Out[11]: 
0    67
1     1
2    23
Name: Use, dtype: int64
```

---

With `header=None`, the column names are 0, 1, ..., 6:

```
In [7]: df = pd.read_csv('data', sep=',', header=None)

In [8]: df
Out[8]: 
            0     1     2      3    4         5    6
0  Filesystem  Size  Used  Avail  Use   Mounted   on
1   /dev/sda3  196G  124G    63G   67         /  NaN
2       tmpfs   32G  144K    32G    1  /dev/shm  NaN
3   /dev/sda1  194M   42M   143M   23     /boot  NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

your DataFrame's columns is 0,1,2,3,4.... if you specify header=None
try with:

> df = pandas.read_csv(tempFolder+"diskSpace.txt", sep=',',header=0)

and also, it's 'Used', not 'Use'